# Sharepoint SPFx ${} replace slash with space in render method

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I'm pretty new to spfx client side development model and there is some stuff that I don't understand.

In sharepoint webpart (SPFx) I'm trying to dynamically load an image src, but if I do: src="${item.ImageUrl}" the slashes (/) are replaced by spaces. But if I do it manually: src="https://picsum.photos/720/300/?image=0", the image is shown without problem.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: can you try it as `<img src={item.ImageUrl} />` no double quotes and no `$` ?

Comment: That just render src={item.ImageUrl} in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake!

```
<img class="${styles.image} src="${item.ImageUrl}" alt="${escape(item.Title)}"  />
```

Its missing the " after the class styles, so for a strange reason the url makes that thing.

This teach me a valuable lesson. If something doesn't work just go home and try tomorrow :)